# Test the SpringBoot application startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I have a JUnit test that starts an spring-boot application (in my case, the main class is `SpringTestDemoApp`) after the test:

```
@WebIntegrationTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringTestDemoApp.class)
public class SpringTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Test http://localhost:8080/ (with Selenium)
    }
}
```

Everything works fine using spring-boot `1.3.3.RELEASE`. Nevertheless, the annotation `@WebIntegrationTest` and `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` have been removed in spring-boot `1.5.2.RELEASE`. I tried to refactor the code to the new version, but I am not able to do it. With the following test, my app is not started before the test and http://localhost:8080 returns 404:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringTestDemoApp.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SpringTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // The same test than before
    }

}
```

How can I refactor my test to make it works in spring-boot 1.5?

Comment: Are you able to see any exception/message in logs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `webEnvironment` option inside `@SpringBootTest` is very important. It can take values like `NONE`, `MOCK`, `RANDOM_PORT`, `DEFINED_PORT`.

- `NONE` will only create spring beans and not any mock the servlet environment.
- `MOCK` will create spring beans and a mock servlet environment.
- `RANDOM_PORT` will start the actual servlet container on a random port; this can be autowired using the `@LocalServerPort`.
- `DEFINED_PORT` will take the defined port in the properties and start the server with it.

The default is `RANDOM_PORT` when you don’t define any `webEnvironment`. So the app may be starting at a different port for you.

Try to override it to `DEFINED_PORT`, or try to autowire the port number and try to run test on that port.

Comment: The default is MOCK, at least with Spring Boot 1.5.10.

Answer (score 4):

It does not work because `SpringBootTest` uses random port by default, please use:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a snippet of what I'm currently using, of course depending on the web-driver you want to use you can create different beans for it.
Make sure you have spring boot test and selenium on your `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

in my case `${selenium.version}` is:

```
<properties>
    <selenium.version>2.53.1</selenium.version>
</properties>
```

and those are the classes:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Import(IntegrationConfiguration.class)
public abstract class AbstractSystemIntegrationTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    protected int serverPort;

    @Autowired
    protected WebDriver driver;

    public String getCompleteLocalUrl(String path) {
        return "http://localhost:" + serverPort + path;
    }
}

public class IntegrationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    private WebDriver htmlUnitWebDriver(Environment env) {
        return new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
    }
}


public class MyWhateverIT extends AbstractSystemIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        driver.get(getCompleteLocalUrl("/whatever-path/you/can/have"));
        WebElement title = driver.findElement(By.id("title-id"));
        Assert.assertThat(title, is(notNullValue()));
    }
}
```

hope it helps!