# Integration tests on spring-boot throws Connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

I have an unit test on Spring Boot:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class CustomerControllerIT {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    @Test
    public void findAllCustomers() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://localhost:8080/Customer", HttpMethod.GET, null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Customer>>() {
                });
        List<Customer> list = responseEntity.getBody();
        Assert.assertEquals(list.size(), 0);
    }
}
```

- If I launch test on started application - tests ok
- If I try to launch only IT, there is connection refused error

My `application.properties` is same for single start.

For tests and located in resources and testResources.

Application.class is:

```
@ComponentScan({"mypackage"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"mypackage.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"mypackage.persistence"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You must run a test with a running server** ,

If you need to start a full running server, you can use random ports:

- **`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`**

> An available port is picked at random each time your test runs

You need this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>        
</dependency>
```

Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TestRest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void findAllCustomers() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
               "/Customer", HttpMethod.GET, null,
               new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Customer>>(){});
        List<Customer> list = responseEntity.getBody();
        Assert.assertEquals(list.size(), 0);
    }
}
```

Please read the documentation for more [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-running-server)

Comment: I had to add server.address in test app.yml to force it to use specific port.

Answer (score 8):

##### For running `@SpringBootTest` and JUnit5 (Jupiter) with static port you can use:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class MyUnitTests {
    @Test
    void checkActuator() throws Exception {
        final String url = "http://localhost:8080/actuator/health";
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        ResponseEntity<Map> re = new RestTemplate().getForEntity(url, Map.class);
        System.out.println(re);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, re.getStatusCode());
        re.getStatusCode();
    }
}
```

If you're using **JUnit 4**:

- Change: `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`
- To: `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`

And then add the port property to your `application.yml` (inside folder `src/main/resources`):

```
server:
  port: 8080
```

Or if have an `application.properties`:

```
server.port=8080
```

---

#### Reference:

- [How to configure port for a Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/how-to-configure-port-for-a-spring-boot-application)
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port
- [Test the SpringBoot application startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281370/test-the-springboot-application-startup)

Comment: Thanks! For my Junit5 test I changed <code>@RunWith to @ExtendWith </code>., so: <code>@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT) </code>,and then my tests worked.